# Is there a better way to achieve this result than using sscanf?

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I need to scan varied incoming messages from a serial stream to check if they contain this string:

"Everything: Received: switchX yy(y)"

where X = 1 to 9 and yy(y) is "on" or "off". i.e. "Everything: Received: switch4 on" or "Everything: Received: switch2 off" etc.

I am using the following code on an ATMega328 to do the check and pass the relevant variables to the transmit() function:

```
valid_data = sscanf(serial_buffer, "Everything: Received: switch%u %s", &switch_number, command);
if(valid_data == 2)
{
  if(strcmp(command, "on") == 0)
    {
       transmit(switch_number, 1);
    }
    if(strcmp(command, "off") == 0)
    {
       transmit(switch_number, 0);
    }
}
```

The check is triggered when the serial_buffer input ISR detects "\n". '\0' is appended to the serial stream to terminate the string.

It works and I'm not pushed for space/processing power but I just wondered if this is the best way to achieve the required result?

Comment: You could write a generic parser if you wanted, or use [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) to find the right offsets to start reading.

Comment: "Best" way by what metric(s)? Discussing the pros and cons of various approaches is interesting and meaningful, but not a terribly good fit for SO's Q&A format. In general, I seldom recommend using `scanf` for anything, since it's fairly ill-defined in terms of the delimiters it detects and other such things, instead tending to prefer `fgets` and parsing the resulting string more manually, but if you can get away with it, using `scanf` is more compact.

Comment: `sscanf` is the right tool for the job. You could enforce more strict input format by adding `\n` at the end of the string and improve security by adding `%4s` to make sure that the last token (command) does not overflow your input buffer (it's 4 characters because a `NUL` character is stored at the end of the string, appended automatically by `sscanf`).

Comment: aside: if your first condition matches, use `else` to avoid testing the other.

Comment: As with such parsing problems, please provide the desired outcome if the string does not match the format - or are you suggestion the _string_ is always well formatted?

Comment: @Dolda2000 Concerning [I seldom recommend using scanf for anything,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54078646/is-there-a-better-way-to-achieve-this-result-than-using-sscanf#comment94990858_54078646).  `scanf()` is not used anywhere here except your comment aside form the tag - (tag refers the `scanf()` family).  `scanf()` is a weak function, yet `sscanf()` is quite robust and a good choice here.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. @pbn especially for the points regarding security and tightening up the input requirements. chux - This particular string is always formatted the same. Other strings that don't match are simply discared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works and I'm not pushed for space/processing power but I just wondered if this is the best way to achieve the required result?

It's unclear on which criteria you want us to judge, since neither speed nor memory usage is a pressing concern, but in the absence of pressure from those considerations I personally rate code simplicity and clarity as the most important criteria for source code, other than correctness, of course.

From that perspective, a solution based on `sscanf()` is good, especially with a comparatively simple format string such as you in fact have.  The pattern for the lines you want to match is pretty clear in the format string, and the following logic is clear and simple, too.  As a bonus, it also should produce small code, since a library function does most of the work, and it is reasonable to hope that the implementation has put some effort into optimizing that function for good performance, so it's probably a win even on those criteria with which you were not too concerned.

There are, however, some possible correctness issues:

- `sscanf()` does not match whitespace literally.  A run of one or more whitespace characters in the format string matches any run of zero or more whitespace characters in the input.
- `sscanf()` skips leading whitespace before most fields, and before `%u` fields in particular.
- switch numbers outside the specified range of 1 - 9 can be scanned.
- the command buffer can easily be overrun.
- `sscanf()` will ignore anything in the input string after the last field match

All of those issues can be dealt with, if needed.  Here, for instance, is an alternative that handles all of them except the amount of whitespace between words (but including avoiding whitspace between "switch" and the digit):

```
unsigned char switch_number;
int nchars = 0;

int valid_data = sscanf(serial_buffer, "Everything: Received: switch%c %n",
        &switch_number, &nchars);

if (valid_data >= 1 && switch_number - (unsigned) '1' < 9) {
    char *command = serial_buffer + nchars;

    if (strcmp(command, "on") == 0) {
        transmit(switch_number - '0', 1);
    } else if (strcmp(command, "off") == 0) {
        transmit(switch_number - '0', 0);
    }  // else not a match
} // else not a match
```

Key differences from yours include

- the switch number is read via a `%c` directive, which reads a single character without skipping leading whitespace.  The validation condition `switch_number - (unsigned) '1' < 9` ensures that the character read is between '1' and '9'.  It makes use of the fact that unsigned arithmetic wraps around.
- instead of reading the command into a separate buffer, the length of the leading substring is captured via a `%n` directive.  This allows testing the whole tail against "on" and "off", thereby removing the need of an extra buffer, and enabling you to reject lines with trailing words.
- If you want to check that all the whitespace, too, exactly matches, then the `%n` can help with that as well.  For example,

  ```
  if (nchars == 30 && serial_buffer[11] == ' ' && serial_buffer[21] == ' '
          serial_buffer[29] == ' ') // it's OK
  ```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks for your reply.